# Opening a new powershell/windows terminal while react app is running

Tags: powershell, windows-scripting

Hi I made two react apps which should interact with each other(both start with npm start). And I want to ask if it is possible to make a script to run the start up commands like a script file on Linux. (It will be like cd.. npm start then start powershell(not sure about this) then cd ... npm sart)

Sorry if the question is vague

Comment: What would be the purpose of opening a new terminal in between launching the apps?

Comment: Because I wouldn't be able to commands in the current terminal(doesn't let me type while react app is running)

Comment: But I don't understand the connection between the npm apps and the terminal you want to launch. Shouldn't the apps talk to eachother via HTTP?

Comment: They're seperate apps and I'm no sure what you mean by "talk to each other via HTTP"

Comment: Simply put: when app1 needs something from app2, it makes [an http request](https://blog.logrocket.com/5-ways-to-make-http-requests-in-node-js/)

Answer (score 0):

**You are looking for "concurrently",**

```
npm i concurrently --save-dev
```

And then change commands in the "package.json"

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "concurrently --kill-others \"cd backend && node server.js\" \"react-scripts start\"" 
  },
```

Now, You can run all commands at once with this;

```
npm run dev
```